# How can I do when SimpleCursorAdapter(Context, int, Cursor, String[], int[]) is deprecated in android:minSdkVersion="8"

Tags: android

My android:minSdkVersion="8", I have the following code in my app,
but the system display SimpleCursorAdapter(Context, int, Cursor, String[], int[]) is deprecated ,
How can I fix the error when android:minSdkVersion="8".

```
    Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse(valueList[pos]);
    cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null,null);

   String[] cols = new String[] {"body"};
   int[]   views = new int[] {R.id.mylisttext};

   adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                 R.layout.mysimple_list_item_multiple_choice,
                 cur, cols, views);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 constructors for SimpleCursorAdapter.  The one you're using, and there's one with an extra parameter for flags which was added in API level 11.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#SimpleCursorAdapter(android.content.Context, int, android.database.Cursor, java.lang.String[], int[], int)

I believe the original constructor was deprecated because of performance issues.  Here are the flags you can add in the newer constructor:

- FLAG_AUTO_REQUERY - Is deprecated, because it performs Cursor queries on the UI thread - this was probably the reason why the first constructor was deprecated.
- FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER - Better described here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html#FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER

Comment: Thanks! but adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                  R.layout.mysimple_list_item_multiple_choice,
                  cur, cols, views, FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER); don't work